# ERROR: operator does not exist: integer - record

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I am working on one project, in which I have created one calculation as per formula,

```
Workinghours – (Signin hours – (first break + lunch))
```

Follwing is my calculation

```
select (to_char((3608) - ((37832.44) - (1560 + 1800),0),'FM99,999,999'))::character varying as tests
```

I am getting following error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer - record LINE 1: select
(to_char((3608) - ((37832.44) - (1560 + 1800),0),'FM9...
                              ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883 Character: 24
```

Comment: This part: ```((37832.44) - (1560 + 1800),0)``` is a record.  The ,0 seems out of place.

Comment: Use `to_char(3608 - 37832.44 - 1560 + 1800,'FM99,999,999')` no need for some many useless parentheses

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson that is right thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you let me know, if sometimes values not there then I want to add 0, how can I give validation in same query?